# Is the polynomial a zero polynomial?

Tags: analysis, polynomials

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ with $deg[p(x)]\leqslant n$. 
If $p(1)=p(2)=\cdots = p(n+1)=0$, then will the polynomial be necessarily a zero polynomial?

i.e., if a polynomial of degree $n$ takes the value zero at $n+1$ distinct points, will the polynomial be necessarily a zero polynomial?

Comment: What do you think? Do you know any nice (fundamental) theorems you could apply?

Comment: Yes, got! Fundamental theorem of algebra : every non-zero single variable degree $n$ polynomial has exactly $n$ roots.

Comment: @supremum, no, the FTA is not needed here. The FTA is about existence. The bound on the number of roots works for every field.

Comment: $deg[p(x)]⩽n$ and $p(i)=0$, $\forall i \in [1,n+1]$ \imples the number of roots of $p(x)$ is grater than its degree. Hence using Fundamental Theorem of Algebra we get p(x) is necessarily a zero polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* If $p(a)=0$, then you can write $p(x)=(x-a)q(x)$. Consider how many times you can do that.

Solution:

> If $p\ne0$, then $p(x)=(x-a)q(x)$ implies $\deg(p)=1+\deg(q)$. If you're given $m$ roots of $p$, then this implies that $\deg(p)\ge m$. This contradicts $p\ne0$ if you're given $n+1$ roots. Said positively, a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots. (And this does not need the FTA.)

Comment: $deg[p(x)]$ times..

Comment: @supremum, exactly, and you don't need the FTA for that. The argument above is elementary and general. The FTA is neither.

Comment: and then the remaining $q'(x)$ has degree zero.

Comment: but for this method you have to know that every polynomial of degree $\geq1$ has at least one zero...

Comment: If we assume $p(1)=p(2)=\cdots=p(n+1)=0$ then, $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-(n+1))q(x)$, then $deg[p(x)]>n$ and hence a contradiction to our assumption $deg[p(x)]\leq n$.

Comment: @lhf : but we are getting the contradiction on number of roots itself, so FTA is inherent here, right?

Comment: @supremum You *are given* $n+1$ roots. No need of finding one, you already have plenty of them.

Comment: @egerg : Where am I *finding one* root? I am just using the given $n+1$ roots to get a contradiction to non-zeroness and degree of the polynomial less than or equal to $n$ happening together.